# How can I create a conditional sentence for each key in a DropDownMenu map?

Tags: flutter, dart

I know this can be hella standard for most of you guys, but I'm pretty new with Dart and I'm having trouble to find out a way to create a if-else statement for each key in [this map I made.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QS3Q.png)

This '*_ramoAtividade*' holds the key/value for a DropDownMenu, where the user select an item. As you can observe, each key holds a specific double value, and I want to set a exclusive if-else statement depending on the calculations I get [by this function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATF7N.png)

If the user choose "Industrial" in the DropDownMenu, and the calculation of '*debCalc*' return less than the "Industrial" value (2.5), then it should return "User not allowed to promotion", but if the result of '*debCalc*' is more than the selected item in the DropDownMenu, then it returns "User allowed to promotion".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the list of DropdownMenuItems for a `Map<String, dynamic> map = {somedata}` dynamically, use:

```
List<DropdownMenuItem>[
  for(final String key in map.keys) DropdownMenuItem(
    value: map[key],
    child: Text(key),
  );
]
```

Your onChanged function:

```
onChanged: (double newValue) {
    // do the necessary calculations with your value
},
```

final code for your button:

```
DropdownButton<double>(

    onChanged: (double newValue) {
        // do the necessary calculations with your value
        debCalc(newValue);
    },

    items: <DropdownMenuItem<double>>[
      for(final String key in _ramoAtividade.keys) DropdownMenuItem<double>(
        value: map[key],
        child: Text(key),
      );
    ],

),
```

Comment: note that the [for(data in list) value] notation works since dart 2.3 and wont run on previous versions.

Comment: But can you tell me how can I extract the key of _ramoAtividade as a variable and use this variable inside some if-else statement inside the _submitSimulation function?

Comment: forgive me my poor comprehencion, but the keys in your map are Strings. What would you use a String for in that function? as far as I see, it needs only to return whether your calculation is more or less than that selected double.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Alexey! I was able to do what I needed by extracting the value through *onChanged:*

Comment: Glad I could help.